# Static libraries. Importing and exporting inline functions

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, inline

This question arose while I was implementing my static library.
I want to *check my guess and gain information* on using inline functions in static libs.

- **My guess is that an iplementator of a static lib can not export an inline function in his library**
  Due to the inline statement is 
  implemented by a compiler(it is up to the compiler whether to make 
  the function inline) by placing low level commands representing 
  operations in the function body to the code segment so that 
  operations won't be placed in the tables of export/import and 
  therefore can't be processed by linker and therefore can't be 
  included by librarian to the code of application to which static lib 
  is attached. Is my logic right?
- **I guess that importing function as inline is allowed but I wonder how it is implemented**, because it is compiler`s
     responsibility but on the linkage state there is only librarian, so
     that means that it must undertake some actions in order to make
     function inline.

Comment: inline function will always be defined in the header, so compiler will see it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, inline functions are typically placed in a header, so the function body is directly visible to the compiler everywhere the function is used. This lets the compiler evaluate whether to generate inline code for the function in any particular instance.
2. This basically doesn't arise -- "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used." (§3.2/3). That means if the compiler is going to generate the function inline, what goes into the library is object code that includes inline expansion of the code for that function. Since it's possible that function may not be expanded inline at every use, there will also typically be a definition of the function in the library, but that definition will be used (at least primarily) like a normal function, not expanded inline.

Linkers can also generate code though. Regardless of whether a function is or isn't an `inline` function by the language standard, and is defined in the same or a different translation unit from the one where it's used, the linker may be able to generate inline code for it anyway.

To make a long story short, the `inline` keyword has little or no effect on a typical compiler as far as whether a function's code will be generated inline or not. The main (if not sole) effect is that it changes the one-definition rule -- being inline means that multiple (identical) definitions of the same function can exist without causing a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand the keyword `inline` - you could equally use replace.

An inline function enables the compile if so choosing to replace the function call with the actual code - nothing to export/import. It is defined in the header file. Anything that uses the object code will require that header code and thus the compiler will replace the function call with the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

On Visual C++ you can use Microsoft specific behavior, and export/import inline functions with `__declspec(dllexport) inline` or `extern inline`. Note that this is Microsoft specific behavior, if you target anything but Windows and are not concerned at all with portability, you could consider it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but now I don't now how to avoid this special behaviour: why `dllexport` implies `extern`? Nobody know why, it looks like this is internal surprise from microsoft.